# Show $f$ is infinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $E$ is a compact Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let, $$f(t) = \int_E \cos(tx) \, dx, \hspace{1mm} t \in \mathbb{R}$$

Show that $f$ is infinitely differentiable.

I have a solution using the mean value theorem, induction, and Lebesgue dominated convergence. However, it seems like a bit of overkill. I am wondering if there is a nice proof to the above problem.

Comment: Why do you think it is overkill? Those theorems are pretty down to earth.

Comment: You are taking a derivative and will need to pass the limit through the integral sign somehow, either directly onto the function inside or on some approximation. Therefore you *need* some kind of theorem to allow this and dominated convergence is just fine.